# Can't change the preferences of Firefox with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I would like to open a Firefox profile with certain preferences using Selenium. But I can't change the preferences, it always loads the page with the default ones.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile

profiles = FirefoxProfile('Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\my.profile')
profiles.set_preference("browser.link.open_newwindow", 3)
profiles.update_preferences()

browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profiles, executable_path='Drivers\\geckodriver.exe')

browser.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=Example')
```